# How do I run selenium in android phone

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, termux

Hii when I use seledroid In my android phone using Termux it throws an error

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class 
{com.luanon.chromium/
com.luanon.chromium.SplashActivity} 
does not exist.
```

And this is my code

```
from seledroid import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can run web automation like selenium in **proot-distro** in **Termux** on Android.

https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/ujhd77/comment/i7mzkvx/